# How to "reuse" instance definitions from another typeclass while introduding minor differences?

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass, ghc-generics

I want to output my application's logs in JSON, but there are some ubiquitous data-types for which `ToJSON` instances are not defined - most notably `SomeException` and the entire `Exception` hierarchy of types.

I have two choices:

1. Define instances of `ToJSON` for such data-types in my application
2. Write my own type-class, say `ToJsonLogs`, and make it reuse `ToJSON` instances as much as possible.

The first is the path of "least resistance" but it has other implications. Since type-class instances are global in nature, I might end-up defining `ToJSON` instances that break something. Also, for the same data-structure, I might want the JSON in APIs to be different from the JSON in logs (for example, scrubbing keys, auth-tokens, and other sensitive data OR truncating very long text fields).

**This questions is about exploring the second option.** How do I go about doing something like the following:

```
class ToJsonLogs a where
  toJsonLogs :: a -> Aeson.Value

  default toJsonLogs :: (ToJSON a) => a -> Aeson.Value
  toJsonLogs = toJSON

instance ToJsonLogs SomeException where
  toJsonLogs = toJSON . displayException
```

I tried the above idea, but it failed at the very first step itself. Here's an example data-structure:

```
data SyncResult = SyncResult
  { resAborted :: !Bool
  , resSuccessful :: !Int
  , resFailed :: ![(Int, SomeException)]
  } deriving (Show)
```

I can't derive `ToJsonLogs` without first deriving `ToJSON` for the entire data-structure. Derivation of `ToJSON` fails because of `SomeException`. Hence the title of this question.

I even tried fooling around with Generics, but as usual, [got stuck again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518275/defining-an-mempty-like-function-with-ghc-generics).

Comment: Another possibility is to use wrapped versions of the instance-less types, which have your custom instances. `resFailed :: [(Int, MyException)]` where `MyException` is a newtype wrapper around `SomeException`

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to a possible extension-free solution. The thing you should consider is to create a wrapper for the original `ToJson` class members:

```hs
class ToJsonLogs a where
  toJsonLogs :: a -> Aeson.Value

newtype WrapToJson a = WrapToJson a  -- actually an Identity

instance ToJson a => ToJsonLogs (WrapToJson a) where
  toJsonLogs (WrapToJson x) = toJson x

-- example
logInt :: Int -> Aeson.value
logInt x = toJsonLogs (WrapJson x)
```

If you want to restrict the wrapper only for `ToJson` instances, you will need to enable few extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax, ExistentialQuantifiaction #-}
data WrapToJson a where WrapToJson :: ToJson a => a -> WrapToJson a
```

If you don't enjoy this wrapper, you may hide it under another definition of `toJsonLogs`:

```
toJsonLogs' :: ToJson a => a -> Aeson.value
toJsonLogs' = toJsonLogs . WrapToJson
```

Comment: Not sure how well will it play with generics tho